# 2-D heat equation being parabolic?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, parabolic-pde

This is a mighty dumb question but I can not seem to figure out how a 2-D heat equation is parabolic. 
  $$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\Delta u $$
I know that the discriminant : $b^2-ac=0$ for a parabolic PDE.

Here, $b=0,a=c=-1$ . Then how is it parabolic ? 
I think I am missing out something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u$ is a function of $x$ and $t$. In the discriminant, $c$ is the co-efficient of $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}$, which is $0$, so the discriminant is indeed $0$.

Comment: Isn't $c$ the co-efficient of $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}$  and $a$ is the co-efficient of $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$ ? ?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_partial_differential_equation for the general case. The key point is that there is no term in $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}$ or in $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial t}$ or in $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y \partial t}$.

Comment: I think I misinterpreted the general case. The function is $u(x,y)$ in the general case but in this heat equation it is $u(x,t)$;hence, $c=0$. Your answer was clear.